# We definitely can't call any wide-character formatting function from DISPATCH_LEVEL, can we?

Tags: device-driver, windows-kernel

When developing Windows kernel-mode driver, I'm considering calling wide-string formatting functions, like `swprintf`, to generate some log messages. But today, I feel so thwarted.

Look at this simple statements:

```
WCHAR wbuf[100];
swprintf(wbuf, L"{%d}", 123);
```

Do you think it is safe to execut in DISPATCH_LEVEL? I find it No, because `swprintf` will definitely call into a pageable function `RtlAnsiCharToUnicodeChar`, so, it will sooner or later result in IRQ_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Bugcheck.

So I'd like to know, does Microsoft really refuse to provide a way to let us do WCHAR string formatting in Windows kernel? Or is there some esoteric function to do that?

This screenshot shows the evidence.

[image: snap9149 swprintf will definitely call RtlAnsiCharToUnicodeChar.png]

Comment: Pretty ranty, never a good way to ask for help.  Real Kernel Programmers use UNICODE_STRING and write their own library functions.  In 5 feet of snow.  Uphill.  Both ways.

Comment: Well, I finally use my self-forged swprintf -- except that I'm not be able to format floating point numbers, which is too complex for me now.